# What is the use of extend in angular? what its application?

Tags: angularjs, extend

Why we need to use `angular.extend` here? To whom it returning value

```
return $scope.thingOne + ‘ ‘ + $scope.thingTwo;
```

In my **controller** :

```
app.controller(‘ThingController’, [ ‘$scope’, function($scope) {
  angular.extend($scope, {
    thingOne: ‘one’,
    thingTwo: ‘two’,
    getThings: function() { 
        return $scope.thingOne + ‘ ‘ + $scope.thingTwo; 
    }
  });
}]);
```

Comment: Have a look at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend

Comment: i chkd dat.. from three doubt comes. pls hlp

Comment: Extend will extend your object with new keys found in source objects

Comment: is it use to copy objects one to onother?